# Android ContentProvider and AsyncQueryHandler

Tags: android, sqlite, cursor, size, android-contentprovider

I am experiencing the problem of crossing the SQLite database size of Android.

I do all the opening and closing operations; I use Singleton; I can seem to get a Cursor close error; But I do not understand where I'm currently making a mistake.

```
CursorWindow: Could not allocate CursorWindow 'db path' of size 2097152 due to error -24.
        AsyncQuery: Exception thrown during handling EVENT_ARG_QUERY
        android.database.CursorWindowAllocationException: Cursor window allocation of 2048 kb failed. # Open Cursors=963 (# cursors opened by this proc=963)
        at android.database.CursorWindow.<init>(CursorWindow.java:108)
        at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.clearOrCreateWindow(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:198)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor.fillWindow(SQLiteCursor.java:138)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor.getCount(SQLiteCursor.java:132)
        at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:773)
        at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:704)
        at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:662)
        at android.content.AsyncQueryHandler$WorkerHandler.handleMessage(AsyncQueryHandler.java:79)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:65)
```

Comment: Are you querying in a loop? If so close the cursors within that loop.

Comment: I am in a loop but I can not catch it.